# Filtering by sum of rows - Propel

Tags: php, propel

I have a virtual column in my query like this:
`->withColumn('SUM(retoure_menge)', 'return_quantity')`
and I want to filter my query to only have this sum greater than zero.
How can I do something similar to

```
->filterByReturnQuantity(array('min' => 0))
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
$query->withColumn('SUM(retoure_menge)', 'return_quantity')
    ->where('return_quantity > 0')
    ->find();
```